# Gathering two plots together in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

I have minimum and maximum values for each group. In one file, I added minimum values, and to the second one I added the maximum values of each group. I am trying to have bar graphs that shows minimum and maximum values separately for each group.

````
p1 <- ggplot (Graph, aes(x=Data_Origin, y=Min))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue", alpha = 0.5) +
  xlab("Data Origin") +
  ylab("Concentration (part/kg-1)")+
   geom_text(aes(label=Min), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5)+
  theme_minimal()

 
 p2 <-ggplot (Graph, aes(x=Data_Origin, y=Max))+ 
   geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue", alpha = 0.8) +
   xlab("Data Origin") +
   ylab("Concentration (part/kg-1)")+
   geom_text(aes(label=Max), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5)+
   theme_minimal()

p1+p2 ```

I receive following error: 

Error in `ggplot_add()`:
! Can't add `p2` to a <ggplot> object.


How can I do it?
````

Comment: Did you load `library(patchwork)`? Here is info on [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com) package.

Comment: if need be, elongate your data using `pivot_longer` and invoke `facet_wrap`

Comment: When I use patchwork, I receive two different graphs separately. But I want them to be in the same graph

Comment: How do I do that Onyambu?

Comment: something in the lines of `data %>% pivot_longer(c(Min, Max)) %>% ggplot(x = Data_Origin, y = value) + geom_col()+facet_wrap(~name)`. We do not have your data to test on. You are the only one with access to the data. You should consider posting some data

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to your data format, so I will try to answer this on the generic `iris` data.

```
library(tidyverse)
data("iris")

df_sum <- iris |>
   group_by(Species) |>
   summarise(min_pet = min(Petal.Length),
             max_pet = max(Petal.Length)) |>
   ungroup() |>
   pivot_longer(cols = min_pet:max_pet,
                values_to = "petal",
                names_to = "dim")
```

The key operation above is to pivot the data you have from a wide format (with `min_pet` and `max_pet` as separate columns) into a long one, where both values for minimum and maximum are stored in the same column.

From this point, there are 2 ways of getting where you need to go. The first is the standard dodged bar plot.

```
ggplot(df_sum,
       aes(x = Species,
                 y = petal,
                 fill = dim)) +
       geom_col(position = "dodge") +
       scale_fill_discrete(name = "Dimension",
                           breaks = c("max_pet", "min_pet"),
                           labels = c("Maximum", "Minimum")) +
       theme_bw() +
       labs(x = "Species",
            y = "Petal Length")
```

This produces the following format.

[image: Dodged bar plot]

The second is a faceted plot.

```
df_sum <- df_sum |>
    mutate(dim = factor(dim,
                        levels = c("max_pet", "min_pet"),
                        labels = c("Maximum", "Minimum")))
  ggplot(df_sum,
         aes(x = Species,
             y = petal)) +
    geom_col() +
    facet_wrap(. ~ dim, ncol = 2) +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(x = "Species",
         y = "Petal Length")
```

[image: Faceted plot]